# Get all documents where nested key name ends with a string

Tags: mongodb

I have following key structure in documents in MongoDB:

`"AAABBB.CCCDDD.EEEFFF.GGGHHH"`

for some documents the structure is different for 3rd part:

```
"AAABBB.CCCDDD.ZZZ**FFF**.GGGHHH"

"AAABBB.CCCDDD.WAW**FFF**.GGGHHH"

"AAABBB.CCCDDD.***FFF**.GGGHHH"
```

that always ends with 'FFF'

Using Mongo intellishell, how to list all documents who's 3rd key ends with FFF?

In other words, how to query for field "GGGHHH" where parent key is paramterized (in a way that key name ends with "FFF"):

```
{ "AAABBB.CCCDDD.EEEFFF.GGGHHH": "12345" }

{ "AAABBB.CCCDDD.ZZZFFF.GGGHHH": "12346" }

{ "AAABBB.CCCDDD.WAWFFF.GGGHHH": "12347" }
```

Comment: Have you tried with`$regex`?

Comment: you can not query on key in mongodb